# how to find the first and last letters of a word

Tags: python

I have a task to find if a word starts with an o ends with a t or both. For finding if it starts or ends the code works fine . For the both part it doesn't work but I cant find the problem. It should return onetwo if the word starts with o and ends with t.

```
def one_two(word):

    if word[0] == "o":
        return "one"
    if word[-1] == "t":
        return "two"
    if word[0] == "o" and word[-1] == "t":
        return "onetwo"

assert (one_two("only") == "one")
assert (one_two("cart") == "two")
assert (one_two("o+++t") == "onetwo")
```

Comment: just put the check for both first!

Comment: You need to put the onetwo check before the others. Right now it will see that the first condition is true, and return immediately. It won't get to the onetwo check.

Comment: Using a debugger would have made this very clear very quickly.

Comment: Depending on the version of python you are running, you might want to use [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) for the sake of readability

Comment: @joshmeranda How might that depend on the Python version?

Comment: @KellyBundy  looking at the [string docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string) for python 2.7 there are no `endswith` or `startswith` methods, so if you are running python 2.7 you would not have access to those methods. Looks like they were introduced for python 3.5.

Comment: @joshmeranda Look for `str` instead of `string`, for example [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.startswith) was changed in 2.5, so apparently existed at least since 2.4.

Comment: @KellyBundy oops you're absolutely right, my mistake. Than in general I would suggest using the `endswith` and `startswith` methods I mentioned before for the sake of improving readbility

Comment: @joshmeranda Yeah, and they also have the advantage of working for empty input without extra effort (e.g., `''.startswith('o')` doesn't crash like `''[0] == 'o'` does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check first if both conditions are true, if not the both case would never execute:

```
def one_two(word):
    if word == "":
        return "empty"
    if word[0] == "o" and word[-1] == "t":
        return "onetwo"
    elif word[0] == "o":
        return "one"
    elif word[-1] == "t":
        return "two"
    
print(one_two("only") == "one")
print(one_two("cart") == "two")
print(one_two("o+++t") == "onetwo")
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you'd need to check the last condition first, as it's checking both the first and last letter. Note that you can keep the multiple `if` statements if you want, rather than switch to use `elif`, because the `return` statements break out of the function early in any case.

```py
def one_two(word):
    try:
        fw, *_, lw = word
    except ValueError:  # empty string, or string is too short
        if not word:
            return None
        fw, lw = word, word

    if (fw, lw) == ('o', 't'):
        return 'onetwo'
    if fw == 'o':
        return 'one'
    if lw == 't':
        return 'two'


assert (one_two("only") == "one")
assert (one_two("cart") == "two")
print(one_two("o+++t"))
assert (one_two("o+++t") == "onetwo")
# edge cases
assert one_two('') is None
assert one_two('o') == 'one'
assert one_two('t') == 'two'
assert one_two('ot') == 'onetwo'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are saying return so code doesn't continue
you can try check it otherway around or simply go like this:

```
def one_two(word):
    msg = ""
    if word[0] == "o":
       msg += "one"
    if word[-1] == "t":
       msg += "two"
    return msg

assert (one_two("only") == "one")
assert (one_two("cart") == "two")
assert (one_two("o+++t") == "onetwo")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def one_two(word):
    return {'o': 'one'}.get(word[0], '') + {'t': 'two'}.get(word[-1], '') if len(word) else ''
```

Comment: `return "one" * (word[:1] == "o") + "two" * (word[-1:] == "t")`